# Как динамически изменить тему Activity

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, settings

я еще только учусь программировать и у меня возникла проблема при изменении темы приложения, в идеале я хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс в настройках тема в самих настройках и в приложении менялась со светлой на темную сразу же, но почему то тема в настройках меняется только при открытии их повторно а главной Активности только после перезапуска приложения, хотя во второй Активности тема меняется при повторном ее открытии. Я что то делаю не так и не могу понять что, прошу вашей помощи в этом, буду признателен за любые ответы.

Ниже прилагаю код моего приложения.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.testsettings;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String LOG = "log";

private void setTheme() {
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("enabled", false)) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    } else {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG, "onCreate");
    setTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(LOG, "onResume");
    setTheme();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(LOG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(LOG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d(LOG, "onStart");
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(LOG, "onStop");
    super.onStop();
}

public void setPrefs(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onclick(View view) {
    Intent intentA = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    intentA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intentA);
}
```

}

**Main2Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private void setTheme() {
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("enabled", false)) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    } else {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

}
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
private void setTheme() {
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("enabled", false)) {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    } else {
        this.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.prefs_content, fragment).commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String string){
    if (string.equals("enabled")){
        this.finish();
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
        this.setResult(-1, new Intent());
    }
}
```

**Settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
android:title="Theme"
android:key="prefs_key">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="enabled"
    android:summary="Темная тема"
    android:title="dark"
    android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Comment: Может быть, вам будет полезно посмотреть это: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qsHE3TpJqw

Comment: Благодарю за пример, самое забавное что я сделал так же как в примере, у меня меняется фон в setting activity но в main activity все равно фон меняется только после перезапуска приложения, хотя в onCreate main activity прописана проверка на положение свича. В других активностях все отлично отрабатывает, не могу понять в чем загвоздка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для смены темы внутри метода `onCreate()` в Activity необходимо прописать два метода: `setTheme()` и `setContentView()`, которые Вы успешно прописали в коде. Однако тема меняется только после вызова метода `onCreate()`. Вы сейчас пересоздаёте свою верхнюю Activity (тем самым вызывая `onCreate()` у данной Activity), однако забываете про тот стек Activity, который вы открывали ранее. Их вы НЕ пересоздаёте, следовательно в них у Вас тема НЕ меняется. Как пересоздать весь стек Activity хорошо объясняется в данном ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799124/7120432

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря ответу выше получилось изменить тему в главной активности дополнив медод onStop в MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();     
}
```